# mlDeploy and token substitution

Tags: deployment, marklogic

During deployment, mlDeploy says it can substitute tokens like server name, users, passwords in "JSON/XML files".  Can that substitution be extended to also look at XQY and SJS files?

Answer (score 1):

That capability exists, see https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/How-modules-are-loaded#replacing-tokens-in-modules .